# Google Spreadsheet unable to deploy web app script --

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to deploy this web app bound to my shared spreadsheet. Basically it's a script that locks a cell after it's been edited. It is working just fine when I access it, however when I switch to another user and try, it doesn't function. You would think it would be a sharing permission setting, but I've changed everything to public and still no luck. Can you someone please help?

Here is the script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567891011');
}

 function onEdit(){ 
  var masterSheetName = "PlaceYourSquare" // sheet where the cells are protected from updates
  var helperSheetName = "Helper" // sheet where the values are copied for later checking
  var firstDataRow = 1; // only take into account edits on or below this row
  var firstDataColumn = 1; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;

  var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn) return;

  var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
  var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
  var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
  var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

  if (oldValue == "") {
    helperCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
    masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Describe exactly what the settings are since your statements are vague. Describe as "publish> "... and then exactly what settings you choose for each field.

Comment: I included a screen shot. Does it help at all? Thank you, Sujay.

Comment: `doGet()` needs to return something.  It either returns HTML to the browser tab, or returns something to an HTTPS GET request.  Deploying the script as a Web App won't do anything.  And `onEdit()` is a simple trigger that has nothing to do with a Web App.  The Web App permissions are different than the file sharing permissions.  Whether the project is deployed as a Web App or not, won't affect how the `onEdit()` trigger works.  You can set file sharing permissions in Drive by right clicking the file.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy -- what should I request to return? Would it be something like this?

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')

Comment: That comment is wrong. doGet() doesn't necessarily need to return something. But in your case, you don't really want a "webapp" right, since your other user will be accessing this sheet. so delete the doGet().  When you run it for another user as a web-app, there is no concept of "active spreadsheet" since the user doesn't have any spreadsheet open.

Comment: The script in the other user's shared sheet will be active. The problem is since you've specified "anyone, even anonymous", there is no "active spreadsheet" since you're simply sharing the URL. What you need is not to publish this as a web-app at all, since you're already sharing the sheet it is bound to.

Comment: Now, sharing permissions should be "execute as: user accessing the app", "who has access: Anyone". In this way, the other user will have to authenticate, in order to use the script within the shared spreadsheet. see if it works now.

Comment: Thanks -- I think I'm still a little confused. So, here's what I've done so far.

First. I added the app code for "onEdit" (from above) minus the doGet command. This works just fine when I am accessing the sheet. It's when I go to the URL as someone else that it does not work.

Second. I added it as a webapp with the command "doGet", created a new version before saving and deploying. When I ran that, authenticated the app (as an outside user), this was returned..."Script function not found: doGet"

Comment: I really just want to be able to share this sheet with the current functionality. I even tried publishing it to a google site and ran up against the same issues.

Comment: As I am trying to explain to you, when you share a sheet with another user, you do NOT need to publish the script as a web-app. The script already resides in the sheet. Hence you don't need any specific web-app authorization, since you're not publishing a web-app. do this: remove doGet(),  Share the sheet with edit permissions with another user. Now with the link the other user got in their email, click on it, login as that other user and execute the script. Done. see if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, it does work that way. I am sending this to multiple people (upwards of 30-40) to edit (i.e., fill in a cell is all) and I don't think they'll all be able to execute the script if I sent to each individually. I was trying to make it accessible via the web to save me a lot of headache. I'll keep plugging away. I've taken up a lot of your time already, but thank you very much for the help. Very much appreciated.